# Need regular expression for this string

Tags: regex, string

I am writing a small program to do some calculations.

Basically the input is the following:

```
-91 10 -4 5
```

The digits can have the negative sign or not. They are also separated by a space. 
I need a regular expression  to filter each digit including the sign if there is one.

Thanks!

Adam

Comment: Take a look at http://www.txt2re.com/ it ought to help with a lot of this sort of problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in PHP:

```
$digit=explode(' ', $digitstring);
echo $digit[0]; // return -91
```

you don't need a regex for this, in PHP.

There are also similar library in other language, such as .Net.

```
string.split(new char[]{' '});
```

Here's an example in ruby:

```
@m=@digitstring.split(' ')
@my=@m[0];  //-91
```

Comment: all his other questions are about ruby... so I'm guessing he wants ruby

Comment: you guys are awesome xD. Yes I am indeed writing in Ruby and the split function worked super well!! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
(-?\d+)\s?
```

You have to match n times and get the first group from your matcher.

Pseudo code:

```
matcher = "-91 10 -4 5".match(/(-\d+)\s?/)
while(matcher.hasMatch()) aNumber = match.group(1);
```

**It's easier without regex**:

```
for(x : "-91 10 -4 5".split()) parseInt(x);
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want:

```
(?<=\b)-?\d+(?=\b)
```

This means:

- Match (but don't capture) a word boundary (space or beginning of string in this case);
- Optionally match and capture the hyphen;
- Match and capture one or more digits; and
- Match but don't capture a trailing word boundary (being a space or the end of the string in this case).

The non-capturing expressions above are [zero-width assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), technically a positive lookbehind and positive lookahead (respectively).